# How to get other fields by passing list of ids for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to get all fields by passing list of employee ids. Help me to fix this issue in my code.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeeByIdsAsync(IEnumerable<int> EmpidList)
{
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    var constr = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    var Client = new MongoClient(constr);
    var DB = Client.GetDatabase("POC");
    var collection = DB.GetCollection<Employee>("Records");
    var plant = Builders<Employee>.Filter;
       
    var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.ElemMatch(s => s.Emp_ID,x=> x.Emp_ID.Equals(EmpidLis)t);
    var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
     

    return empList;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the definition of `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `In` instead of `ElemMatch`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> 
    GetEmployeeByIdsAsync(IEnumerable<int> EmpidList)
{
     List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    var constr = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
   var Client = new MongoClient(constr);
  var DB = Client.GetDatabase("POC");
     var collection = DB.GetCollection<Employee>("Records");
   var plant = Builders<Employee>.Filter;
   
    var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.In(s => s.Emp_ID, EmpidList);
    var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
 

   return empList;
 }

}
```